# Comparing an array object to string using mocha && chai.

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am using mocha and chai for the first time and have no idea what is going on? im trying to say that my shuffle method has moved the array objects around and the first array object no longer - "sam1"   IE -

```
describe('Shuffle', function(){

it('Shuffle should randomly move array items by their index', function(){
    let group = ["sam1","sam2","sam3","sam4","sam5","sam6","sam7","sam8","sam9"];
    let result = shuffle(group);
    assert.equal(result, group[0] != "sam1");
  });
});
```

---

this is the error -

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(9) ] to equal true
```

how do i compare the two to make it true? or is there a better way to show the array has been shuffled?

Comment: I know you didn't ask…but if your shuffle is truly random, it's possible for an item to end up where it started.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`assert.notEqual(group[0], "sam1");`

You can find the list of usable functions here
http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of assert.equal() is where your comparison should be,
so

```
assert.equal(result, group[0] != "sam1");
```

should be

```
assert.equal(comparison, 'message to display on failure');
```

and a better way to know if the array has been shuffled would be to compare every element in the result with the original array, so something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    if (group[i] !== result[i]) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

although, depending on how you shuffle there is a chance it shuffles in to the same order.

see http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/ for more details on assert

Answer (score 0):

It looks like shuffle returns an array. So to check if your first element in `result` array is not the same as in `group` array you have to compare the first two elements of arrays. If you want to use `assert` method, you have to do it this way:

`assert(result[0] != group[0], "string if the test fails");`

Just at the top of this [doc](http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to compare the previous array and after array. Don't use `equal` here but instead `deepEqual` to compare array or object.

```
it('Shuffle should randomly move array items by their index', function(){
    let group = ["sam1","sam2","sam3","sam4","sam5","sam6","sam7","sam8","sam9"];
    let result = shuffle(group);
    assert.deepEqual(result, group);
  });
});
```

Ref: http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(result).to.have.members(group); // to check if all members there - doesn't care about the order
expect(result).to.not.eql(group); // to check if order has changed - there's a catch though; only 1 change on order (e.g. `shuffle` swapped **just** 2 members) is sufficient to this assertion to pass
```

Sources;

- https://medium.com/building-ibotta/testing-arrays-and-objects-with-chai-js-4b372310fe6d
- https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members
- https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql